# LINQ Query Syntax (getting error)

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, linq

I am trying to understand the syntax of a LINQ query.  I tried creating one to select all rows from my TRACK_INFO table where the column collegeOf was equal to a variable.  My database name is KuPlan.    Below is the query I tried to create and my TRACK_INFO model.  The error i get is:  "could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type KU_PLAN_DEV.Models.TRACK_INFO.  'Where' not found."

controller:

```
var query = from degreeName in TRACK_INFO
            where degreeName == trackButton
            select degreeName;
```

model:

```
namespace KU_PLAN_DEV.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class TRACK_INFO
{
    public TRACK_INFO()
    {
        this.CORE_HEAD = new HashSet<CORE_HEAD>();
        this.GEN_ED_HEAD = new HashSet<GEN_ED_HEAD>();
        this.GEN_ED_NOTE = new HashSet<GEN_ED_NOTE>();
        this.GRAD_CLEAR_HEAD = new HashSet<GRAD_CLEAR_HEAD>();
        this.MAJOR_NOTE = new HashSet<MAJOR_NOTE>();
    }

    public string progNum { get; set; }
    public string versionNum { get; set; }
    public string degreeName { get; set; }
    public string collegeOf { get; set; }
    public string effectiveDateTerm { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> effectiveDateYear { get; set; }
    public string trackDegreeType { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CORE_HEAD> CORE_HEAD { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GEN_ED_HEAD> GEN_ED_HEAD { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GEN_ED_NOTE> GEN_ED_NOTE { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GRAD_CLEAR_HEAD> GRAD_CLEAR_HEAD { get; set; }
    public virtual GRAD_CLEAR_SIG_DATE GRAD_CLEAR_SIG_DATE { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MAJOR_NOTE> MAJOR_NOTE { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: you probably meant `collegeOf` in the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

`TRACK_INFO` is a class name, not an `IEnumerable<TRACK_INFO>`. I think you meant to get a property off of your context:

```
        from degreeName in context.TRACK_INFO
        ...
```

Comment: what gets put in place of context then?

Comment: @user3255899: Typically LINQ statements like this would be wrapped in a `using(var context = new MyContext())` statement, where `MyContext` is the name of your Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL context. You've only provided code for the one class, so I don't know what the name of your context is.